# Guice on-demand injection

Tags: java-8, guice, playframework-2.5

I have been learning about Guice. I see that there is an on-demand injection [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#on-demand-injection).

I wanted to know what it is used for and some example. I have a scenario where I read a set of properties from a conf file. There is no injection there. Later on I want to inject the same instance of the config class I have from those properties to some other class.

```
class Props {
    //set of properties read from a config file to this class

}

Props props = readProperties(); // instance of this class having all the properties but not put into injection container
```

Later in connection class I want to use its injection

```
@Inject
public Connection(Props props) {
    this.props = props;
}
```

Is it possible to use on-demand injection of Guice in this case? Also I am using Play framework's conf file to load my module file.
play.modules.enabled += com.example.mymodule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the very same configuration instance (of class Props) you could bind its instance as a [singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) with a [provider binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings). This is of course not the only solution, but it makes sense for me.

Here is an example:

Define a provider:

```
public class PropsProvider implements Provider<Props>
{
    @Override
    public Props get()
    {
        ...read and return Props here...
    }
}
```

Use a provider binding in singleton scope:

```
bind(Props.class).toProvider(PropsProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Inject your configuration:

```
@Inject
public Connection(Props props) {
    this.props = props;
}
```

You may read in the documentation:

> Singletons are most useful for:
>
> - stateful objects, such as configuration or counters
> - objects that are expensive to construct or lookup
> - objects that tie up resources, such as a database connection pool.

Maybe your configuration object matches the first and the second criteria. I would avoid reading the configuration from within the module. See why [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ModulesShouldBeFastAndSideEffectFree).

I've used on-demand injection in a few unit test cases where I wanted to inject mock dependencies in the component under test and field injection was used (that's why I try to avoid field injections :-) ) AND I preferred not to use [InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) for certain reasons.

Here is a sample:

Component:

```
class SomeComponent
{
    @Inject
    Dependency dep;

    void doWork()
    {
        //use dep here
    }
}
```

The test itself:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeComponentTest
{
    @Mock
    private Dependency mockDependency;

    private SomeComponent componentToTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        componentToTest = new SomeComponent();

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractNamingModule()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure()
            {
                bind(Dependency.class).toInstance(mockDependency);
            }
        });

        injector.injectMembers(componentToTest);
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
         //test the component and/or proper interaction with the dependency
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I had a query. I would have liked to use Provider but I am getting a reference to Props from before and I can't read it now. So I just wondered if I could just inject its reference when I get it and use the Injector further wherever I use it.

Comment: There are multiple solutions depending on your context. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the Play FW. BUT... the singleton above is lazy (won't be instantiated until needed) - that means that you can still use a provider with an internal state - e.g. you may use the same provider instance in your module definition and in the place where you read the props just call something like provider.setProps(props) on the same shared instance. This sounds quite dirty though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Load the properties in your module and them via `bindConstant`